# Empty line indentation for Python

Tags: indentation, python

Whenever I press o or O, VIM starts the line with the desired indentation. At work, people have decided that they want empty lines to be indented as if it contained code, such that code can be copied and pasted into an interpreter without empty lines terminating function, if, for, and other similar blocks.

Is there a way to customize the visual mode "=" functionality to adapt for this? And is there a way to make VIM not remove indentation on an indented but otherwise empty line when I leave insert mode?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: It is possible to customize `=` (`equalprg` or `indentexpr`, for example), but I'm not yet sure how to put all the pieces together